# CS-Regression Three Factor Model

Tags: finance, regression, asset-pricing, fama-french

1# When would the three risk factors market, size and value be priced in the FF Three factor model when performing cs-regression? How do you know that they are priced?

2# How would it be possible to interpret the risk premiums of the Thre Factor model. Could somebody give an example?